# If statement within an inner join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, inner-join

Is there a way to have an if statement determine whether a join is necessary or not?

I need this because there are multiple foreign keys in the data I querying. if any of the foreign keys are null I need to change the SQL statement. I would like to write one statement that can be aware of any null values.

This is what I would like to do...

```
select a.*,b.* from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id
if a.InspectorID is not null
{inner join table3 c on a.InspectionID = c.id}
else do nothing...
```

Comment: Can you not use a `left join`? or am I missing the point?

Comment: You can't change the *shape* of a query (tables used, number of columns, names and types of the columns in the result set) without using dynamic SQL. But in this case, what's the point - you never use any columns from `c`?

Comment: I guess I didn't fully understand the left join...christiandev thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out...

```
select a.*,b.* from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id
left join table3 c on a.InspectionID = c.id
where a.InspectorID is null or a.InspectionID = c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, if you can conditionally join tables, but the "if" statement in t-sql is calles
[case](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms181765.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

What about using `union`

```
select a.*,b.* 
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id
inner join table3 c on a.InspectionID = c.id
union all
select a.*,b.* 
from table1 a 
inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id
where a.InspectionID is null
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you could use:

```
select a.*,b.*,c.fields 
from table1 a inner join table2 b on a.id = b.id
left join table3 c on a.InspectionID = c.id
where a.InspectionID IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score -1):

Use dynamic sql. For detail about dynamic sql go through:
http://exacthelp.blogspot.in/2013/02/writing-dynamic-sql-queries-in-sql.html

Comment: Why use dynamic SQL here?